# ASP.NET MVC getting id of selected item in list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm creating my first app using asp.net MVC, having a very hard time.  I simply want to get a single selected item in my list, press my submit button and do something with the selected item.  I feel like I have all the elements here.  But when I press submit I'm getting a null error in my View file (cshtml).  Been all over the web and can't see how to apply what I'm finding to what I have.  Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Model

```
    public List<string> GetFileName { get; set; }
    public List<string> ID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> FileSelect { get; set; }

public async Task ProcessRepo()
{
    string project = "https:...my url";
    string projectToken = "***";

    #region Get List of file names

    // Get list of files***********
    string uri = $"{project}tree?private_token={projectToken}&ref=master";
    string results = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

    FileList files = new FileList();
    FileList id = new FileList();
    GetFileName = files.GetList(results);
    ID = id.GetID(results);

    #endregion
}
```

Controller

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> RepoFiles()
    {
        AssetBrowserModel _repoInfo = new AssetBrowserModel();
        await _repoInfo.ProcessRepo();
        var repoFiles = _repoInfo.GetFileName;

        //Populate list box
        var model = new AssetBrowserModel();
        model.FileSelect = new List<SelectListItem>();
        
        for (int i=0; i < _repoInfo.GetFileName.Count; i++)
        {
            model.FileSelect.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = _repoInfo.GetFileName[i],
                Value = _repoInfo.ID[i].ToString(),
                Selected = false
            });
        }
        
        return View(model);
```

View cshtml

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ID, new SelectList(Model.GetFileName, "Value", "Text"),
    new { @style = "width:300px;height:100px;"})
</div>
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID, new { id = "UserId" })<br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Download" />
    }
</div>
```

FileList

```
class FileList
    {
        public List<string> GetList(string results)
        {
            string stringToCheck = "name";
            List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
            string[] data = results.Split(new[] { ',', '\n' });

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                if (getTreeData[i].Contains(stringToCheck))
                {
                    fileNames.Add(data[i]);
                }
            }
            return fileNames;
        }

public List<string> GetID(string results)
{
    string idToCheck = "id";
    List<string> fileID = new List<string>();
    string[] data = results.Split(new[] { ',', '\n' });

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        if (data[i].Contains(idToCheck))
        {
            string[] newID = data[i].Split(':');
            fileID.Add(newID[1]);
            
        }
    }

    foreach(var x in fileID)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"File ID is: {x}");
    }
    return fileID;
}
```

Comment: where does the error occur?

Comment: I get this error 

'System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items''

at 'new SelectList(Model.GetFileName,....)'

Comment: Well you don't set model.GetFileName (which is a horrible name for a property) anywhere so yeah, exception.

Comment: Please share the code for the Controller method that you submit to.

Comment: @Yong Shun I updated my model to reflect how I'm getting my files.  Model, Controller, View.  I hope that helps clarify.  I had to make a couple of lines vague due to privacy issues.

I will update my naming (David Libido).  This is my first experience in the coding industry and critiques are more than welcomed.  Trying to get better :)

Comment: I'm able to get the files to populate in my list.  I just can't seem to get the value of the item when I select it in my list.

Comment: your begin form not even putting any value inside. you have put in something like @html.HiddenFor(a => a.Id) to pass the Id

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I've since tried adding 

code
`@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID, new { id = "UserId" })<br />` in the beginform.  I still get 404 error.  Been struggling with this quite a bit.



`HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Home/RepoFiles`